# How to group the data based on the color and sum the same size in react

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks

```
data = [
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 12,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 9,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 12,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 12,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 12,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 12,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'pink',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 14,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 14,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 14,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 12,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 14,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'pink',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 14,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'yellow',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 12
      },
      {
        color: 'pink',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 12
      }]
```

How to `merge/group` the array based on the color and size then sum the same value of size.
for example
there's a three data the first data is color red with size `xs` value `12` then the second and third yellow with same size `xs` different value.

```
color | xs | s
red   | 12 | 
yellow | 13 |
yellow | 2 |
yellow | 2 | 12
```

Then the output should be like this:

```
color | xs | s
red   | 12 | 
yellow | 17 | 12
```

The expected output should be like this:

```
 data =   [
              {
                color: 'red',
                _1x: 0,
                _2x: 21,
                _3x: 24,
                _4x: 24,
                xxs: 0,
                xs: 0,
                s: 28,
                m: 26,
                l: 14,
                xl: 0
              },
              {
                color: 'pink',
                _1x: 0,
                _2x: 0,
                _3x: 0,
                _4x: 0,
                xxs: 0,
                xs: 0,
                s: 14,
                m: 0,
                l: 14,
                xl: 12
              },
              },
              {
                color: 'yellow',
                _1x: 0,
                _2x: 0,
                _3x: 0,
                _4x: 0,
                xxs: 0,
                xs: 0,
                s: 0,
                m: 0,
                l: 0,
                xl: 12
              }]
```

CODE: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hook-j4wje4

Comment: what is the expected output object format?

Comment: I think you can do this with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @NinaScholz I already updated and added the expected result on the data

Comment: here's the sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hook-k621ye

Answer (score 1):

You can use `color` as key and group your array based on this key using `array#reduce`. Then you can sum up value of similar size using `array#reduce`.

```js
const data = [ { color: 'red', size: '2X', _1x: 0, _2x: 12, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '2X', _1x: 0, _2x: 9, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '3X', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 12, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '3X', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 12, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '4X', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 12, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '4X', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 12, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'pink', size: 'L', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 14, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: 'L', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 14, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: 'M', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 14, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: 'M', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 12, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: 'S', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 14, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'pink', size: 'S', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 14, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'yellow', size: 'XL', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 12 }, { color: 'pink', size: 'XL', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 12 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, {color, size, ...rest}) => {
      r[color] ||= { color };
      Object.keys(rest).forEach(k => {
        r[color][k] = (r[color][k] || 0) + rest[k];
      });
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I added an expected output

Comment: The output is same as you shared.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hook-mrtyau is it ok to check on it? cause it didn't sum the other sizes

Comment: {
                color: 'red',
                _1x: 0,
                _2x: 21,
                _3x: 24,
                _4x: 24,
                xxs: 0,
                xs: 0,
                s: 28,
                m: 26,
                l: 14,
                xl: 12
              }
 it should be like this. but on the example the output is like this {
        color: 'red',
        size: 'S',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 14,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      }

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you explain the `xl` value of `red`? How does it is 12?

Comment: I already updated on it. is it ok to check this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hook-spry2k cause in color red it only display the size of small it doesn't display the sizes

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

(Note that I use some of your data not whole of them)

```js
const data=[{color:"red",size:"2X",_1x:0,_2x:12,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"2X",_1x:0,_2x:9,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"3X",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:12,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"3X",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:12,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"4X",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:12,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"4X",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:12,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"pink",size:"L",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:14,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"L",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:14,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"M",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:14,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"M",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:12,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"S",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:14,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"S",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:14,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"XL",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:12},{color:"red",size:"XL",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:12},{color:"red",size:"2X",_1x:0,_2x:2,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"3X",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:2,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"4X",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:2,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"L",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:3,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"M",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:14,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"M",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:2,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"S",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:14,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"XL",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:3},{color:"red",size:"XS",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:6,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"2X",_1x:0,_2x:2,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"3X",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:2,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"4X",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:2,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"L",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:3,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"M",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:14,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"M",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:2,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"S",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:14,m:0,l:0,xl:0},{color:"red",size:"XL",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:0,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:3},{color:"red",size:"XS",_1x:0,_2x:0,_3x:0,_4x:0,xxs:0,xs:6,s:0,m:0,l:0,xl:0}];

        var object = {};

        var result = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
            var key = o.color + '|' + o.size;

            if (!object[key]) {
                object[key] = Object.assign({}, { color: o.color, sizes: o.size,  value: o["_" + o.size.toLowerCase()] }); // create a copy of o
                r.push(object[key]);
            } else {
                object[key].value += o["_" + o.size.toLowerCase()];
            }

            return r;
        }, []);

        console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const SIZES = ['_2x', '_3x', '_4x', 'l', 'm', 's', 'xl'];
const data = [
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: '_2X',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 12,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: '_2X',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 9,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: '_3X',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 12,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: '_3X',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 12,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: '_4X',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 12,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: '_4X',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 12,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'pink',
        size: 'L',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 14,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: 'L',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 14,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: 'M',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 14,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: 'M',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 12,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'red',
        size: 'S',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 14,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'pink',
        size: 'S',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 14,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 0
      },
      {
        color: 'yellow',
        size: 'XL',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 12
      },
      {
        color: 'pink',
        size: 'XL',
        _1x: 0,
        _2x: 0,
        _3x: 0,
        _4x: 0,
        xxs: 0,
        xs: 0,
        s: 0,
        m: 0,
        l: 0,
        xl: 12
      }]



console.log(

data.reduce((acc, el) => {
    let colorpos = acc.findIndex(([color]) => color == el.color);
    if(!~colorpos) {
      colorpos = acc.length;
      acc.push([el.color, ...Array.from({length: SIZES.length}).fill(0)])
    };
    const sizepos = SIZES.indexOf(el.size.toLowerCase()) + 1;
    acc[colorpos][sizepos] += el[el.size.toLowerCase()];
    return acc;
}, [
  ['color', ...SIZES]
])
.map(str => str.join('\t|')).join('\n')

);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could take a dynamic approach and specify the wanted keys for grouping.

```js
const
    data = [{ color: 'red', size: '2X', _1x: 0, _2x: 12, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '2X', _1x: 0, _2x: 9, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '3X', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 12, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '3X', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 12, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '4X', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 12, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: '4X', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 12, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'pink', size: 'L', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 14, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: 'L', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 14, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: 'M', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 14, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: 'M', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 12, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'red', size: 'S', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 14, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'pink', size: 'S', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 14, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 0 }, { color: 'yellow', size: 'XL', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 12 }, { color: 'pink', size: 'XL', _1x: 0, _2x: 0, _3x: 0, _4x: 0, xxs: 0, xs: 0, s: 0, m: 0, l: 0, xl: 12 }],
    keys = ['color', 'size'],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = keys.map(k => o[k]).join('|');
        r[key] ??= Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]]));
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (keys.includes(k)) return;
            r[key][k] ??= 0;
            r[key][k] += v;
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hook-j4wje4 it only display the value on small it doesn't display the other value on small

Comment: @BeginnerCoder, you are overwriting a check with assignment `r[key] ??= Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]]));` with an assignment `r[key] = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]]));` in your code. please have a look to the [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), which is necessary to prevent  loosing older collected values.